# Access url params in master controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

My application has two controllers. I have a `pageCtrl`which I use to handle my navigation and sidebar. I also have a `calendarCtrl` for handling the data on my page. This controller is configured as shown below:

```
$stateProvider
  .state('calendar', {
    url: '/calendar/:category/:competition/:team',
    controller: 'calendarCtrl',
    templateUrl: 'app/modules/calendar/calendarView.html',
  })
```

To make my navigation work I also need access to the `:category/:competition/:team`-params in my `pageCtrl`. Can I configure this using the same way? Something like:

```
$stateProvider
  .state("page", {
   abstract: true,
   controller: 'pageCtrl',
   // params: :category/:competition/:team
})
```

Edit: Using `$stateParams` in the `calendarCtrl` works fine. I just can't figure out how I can make sure my `pageCtrl` also can get read the url.

Comment: This is against the principle http://stackoverflow.com/a/24306250/1679310. It cannot be achieved (without hacking the UI-Router architecture) ... sorry for not having The Answer ;(

Comment: So it is not possible to read the url parameters from 2 different controllers at the same time? Is there a 'ui-router'-way of doing something alike?

Comment: I would say, that you should change the approach. Really. There is a solution, but in a totally different approach. We would move the stuff you need on a parent to be consuming params... into child state. Give me sec, I will try to show you

Comment: Comment is not enough, I created a plunker(s) to show the way, which I believe is what the UI-Router founders placed in there for us.. Hope it helps a bit

Answer (score 2):

Since you're using ui.router, inject `$stateParams` in your controller(s) and then you can access those values like so:

**controller.js**

```
function($stateParams){

$stateParams.category
$stateParams.competition
$stateParams.team
```

Comment: the `$stateParams`-variable is empty when I inject it.

Comment: are you sure you're currently within the `calendar` state or a child state of the `page` state?

Comment: @Thijs How do you know? Try console.log($stateParams).

Comment: My url is `/#/calendar/SH/8/2059` so I'm currently in my `calendarCtrl`. I've put a breakpoint in my `pageCtrl`to view the `$stateParams` and it's empty.

Comment: I also tried using `$state` but this variable is also empty.

Comment: `$state` only provides your APIs to your current state objects defined in your original code.  I'd suggest making a jsFiddle for this so we can try to help solve it with code.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be - use more views - the UI-Router built feature.

#### [Multiple Named Views](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Multiple-Named-Views)

There is [a working plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/olz7wOHRnmgtPgrerxJi?p=preview)

Let's have the **`'Parent'`** state which has this template:

This blue is the parent template. Orange are child views

```
<!-- HERE is one named view target -->
<div ui-view="title">This is a title filled by child having access to param</div>

  ...  

<!-- HERE is other view target un-named -->
<div ui-view></div>
```

And its state is very simple. The interesting is the child state, which is taking care about both views:

```
  .state('parent', {
      abstract: true,
      url: "/parent",
      templateUrl: 'tpl.parent.html',
  })
  .state('parent.child', { 
      url: "/child/:id",
      views : {
        '': {
          templateUrl: 'tpl.child.html',
        },
        'title': {
          templateUrl: 'tpl.title.html',
          controller: 'TitleCtrl',
        },
      }
  })
```

So, we do have a target for "some other view" title or side bar. Check it [here](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Multiple-Named-Views)

And we can even place some default implementation there inside of our **"non-abstract"** parent state.

There is [extended plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/nuw3h4sanqTDyH1mWJd6?p=preview) with non abstract parent state definition:

```
  .state('parent', {
      url: "/parent",
      views : {
        '': {
          templateUrl: 'tpl.parent.html',
        },
        'title@parent': {
          template: 'the parent own TITLE',
        },
      }
  })
```

Check it [here](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Multiple-Named-Views)

Comment: The example you've given let child views use the parameters. I'm trying to read the parameters in the parent view.

Comment: I respect that you do not like it. If I could, I would at least ask you to evaluate again if you cannot use this. My second answer does show some way how to go arround... but I would prefer this approach

Answer (score 0):

There is a way, how to grant access to latest/up-to-date `$stateParams` - including current state and its child(ren) as well. *([working example here](http://plnkr.co/edit/yQ4QQF1AEGNW5psAsFZW?p=preview))*

It is surprisingly easy:

```
.run(['$rootScope', '$state', '$stateParams',
  function ($rootScope, $state, $stateParams) {
    $rootScope.$state = $state;
    $rootScope.$stateParams = $stateParams;
}])
```

And that's it. *(check similar [answer and some discussion here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29427162/1679310))*

With this approach, we will even in parent `$scopes` have updated reference to the latest `$stateParams`. While in our own, we will still receive just our own part

```
.controller('ParentCtrl', ['$scope', '$stateParams', function ($scope, $stateParams) {
  $scope.currentStateParams = $stateParams;
}])
```

The above is valid for states like these:

```
.state('parent', {
  url: "/parent?area",
  templateUrl: 'tpl.html',
  controller: 'ParentCtrl',
})
.state('parent.child', { 
  url: "/child/:id",
  templateUrl: 'tpl.html',
  controller: 'ChildCtrl',
})
```

Working [example to play here](http://plnkr.co/edit/yQ4QQF1AEGNW5psAsFZW?p=preview).

*But I still would say, that this is a bit ... against the UI-Router. I would [prefer this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30318867/1679310). Because in that case, each view (while injected into some parent area) is really aware about $stateParams, which belongs to that state. What we are doing here is introduction of some observer pattern (we should watch changes if we want to react in parent) and that would later bring more issues then profit*